# How to save passwords with security but i need to get it as clean text later?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, passwords, password-protection

I going to create a service where people administer the game servers and to administrate the server I need the admin password to run commands to the server.

So I need to save the password with server ip and admin port in a database where I can get out the password and use it when the user wants to do some command to the server.

How I can do this as security as possible? I don't want to save it in plain text in the database and I don't want it to be easy to get the password from the saved hash value if someone gets the database.

I working in ASP.NET MVC 3, C# and MySQL as database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [this link](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/encrypting-decrypting-string/). Triple DES encryption can be encrypted and decrypted using a key. your program will encrypt on the way up and decrypt the DB value when needed. if you want to really be secure you could look into using a salt

Answer (score 1):

You could use [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to store the information.  Each user would have their own public key to encrypt the data, and your service would hold the private key to decrypt the data.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to get the plain text password, nor should you.  You could store the password with a 1-way hash (SHA-1, SHA-2) and salt, and then when you enter a password to validate your credentials, you would hash the input the `same way` that you did when you stored the password in the database.  If the two hash values match, the user should be granted access.

.Net has a [SHA-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) class that you can use so you do not have to write your own.

I'll reiterate, you do not want to be able to get the password as plain text, because in the event that your data is compromised, the attacker can get the password too.

Comment: the OP has clearly stated that they will require the password back in plain text _where I can get out the password and use it when the user wants to do some command to the server_

Comment: @Eonasdan Yes, the OP states that is their goal.  I believe the answer is still to not do that. It is very dangerous, and there are always better ways to authenticate users than to have their passwords in plain text.

Comment: he's not talking about authenticating users. he's talking about saving a password to administrate a secondary service. I agree, however, that authenticating users by comparing plain text is bad.

Comment: I should not ask if its not was the thing that i really need to get the password back and like Adam Wenger alrady sayed, it is not authentication for a user, its more like a authentication for a server and this tool i writing should get the users to not need to know stuff like the password to the server, becouse the idea is that one server admin add the server and some users to get access to the server and then the users only administrate it from my tool.

And every command the user do i need to send password...